# Why did my screens suddenly go gray?

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card

I've been working on my PC tonight, when suddenly the colors all vanished and I was left with only grayscale. On both monitors. What would cause that?

The color has come back, but I've no idea how that happened.

Comment: I was too quick to say that loose cables were the culprit. This morning when I logged into my PC, the display is all in grayscale. I've double checked the connections; everything is tight. So, could I have done something accidentally in Windows 10, to cause this to happen?

Comment: @Rod Have you tried switching the HDMI cable?

Answer (score 0):

If the Windows version is 1709, please check if the Apply color filter in Color filters is ON. (Settings -> Ease of Access -> Color & high contrast). 
You could also press Windows logo key + Ctrl + C.